# Error: "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control XYZ"

Tags: sapui5

I tried to find a solution by checking other questions with a similar error but none could help me. I tried to run the *Component.js* from my app in sandbox. Running the *index.html* works fine. My starting view is this:

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  controllerName="com.sap.build.standard.qrCodeScanner.controller.Home"
>
  <Page id="home"
    class="customHomeBackground"
    showHeader="true"
    title="Home"
    showFooter="true"
  >
    <content>
      <FlexBox
        class="customFlexBoxHome"
        justifyContent="Center"
        alignItems="Center"
        wrap="Wrap"
      >
        <GenericTile class="customTile"
          header="Scan invitations"
          subheader="from your customers"
          frameType="OneByOne"
          press="_onGenericTilePress1"
        >
          <TileContent>
            <ImageContent src="sap-icon://bar-code"/>
          </TileContent>
        </GenericTile>
      </FlexBox>
    </content>
    <footer/>
    <headerContent/>
    <subHeader/>
    <customHeader/>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

It's simply a single `GenericTile`. I can't access this view because of

> Error: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.GenericTile

[image: console error]

Accessing the other views is no problem. So when I add e.g. a button instead of the `GernericTile` + children, it works fine.

I also tried to add one of [these](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.GenericTileAsLaunchTile/preview) sample tiles instead but same error.
What's the problem with the `GenericTile`?

Comment: For other readers: the error can also occur if the child node has a wrong namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190239/5846045 if the solutions here don't apply to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piggybacking on @sunil-b-n's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712322/502613):

In the current version of UI5 the example code works fine, as per the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YBjEr8otqhbqgNCpCo78?p=preview) Sunil provided.

However, if you change the library version to 1.38.15 like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/G9gjSYG3rWUydBz9VfEP?p=preview), it is broken as per OP's question.

Look at the difference. In the latest version, this code is valid:

```xml
<GenericTile>
    <TileContent>
        <ImageContent src=""/>
    </TileContent>
</GenericTile>
```

But in old versions, named aggregations need to be explicitly added accordingly:

```xml
<GenericTile>
    <tileContent> <!-- named aggregation required. Default since 1.46.x -->
        <TileContent>
            <content> <!-- named aggregation required. Default since 1.38.18 -->
                <ImageContent src=""/>
            </content>
        </TileContent>
    </tileContent>
</GenericTile>
```

You need to figure out what version of UI5 you're on and use the [appropriate SDK documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f021426f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) to build your app, otherwise you'll run into trouble.

> You can view the version-specific Demo Kit by adding the version number to the URL, e.g. https://ui5.sap.com/1.38.8/

Answer (score 1):

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="com.sap.build.standard.qrCodeScanner.controller.Home" >
<Page id="home" class="customHomeBackground" showHeader="true" title="Home" showFooter="true">
    <content>
        <FlexBox class="customFlexBoxHome" justifyContent="Center" alignItems="Center" wrap="Wrap">
            <GenericTile class="customTile" header="Scan invitations" subheader="from your customers" frameType="OneByOne" press="_onGenericTilePress1">
                <TileContent>
                    <ImageContent src="sap-icon://bar-code" />
                </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
        </FlexBox>
    </content>
    <footer/>
    <headerContent/>
    <subHeader/>
    <customHeader/>
</Page>
</mvc:View>
```

This view is loading completely fine in the latest SAPUI5 version.
[Working plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/YBjEr8otqhbqgNCpCo78?p=preview)

`content` is the default `aggregation` for [sap.m.Page.](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Page/aggregations)

Answer (score -2):

guess because of the wrapped `sap.m.Page` around the `sap.m.GenericTile`. just omit the `sap.m.Page` and you won't get the error. the sap [fiori design guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/tile/) says that tiles are used to display and launch apps on the launchpad. And therefore, they shall not be used on an overview page or anywhere else.