# Error "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control ..."

Tags: sapui5

I am getting the error "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.Label". Not sure what this means. Here is my fragment:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:f="sap.f">
    <ResponsivePopover id="popover" title="{Name}" class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" placement="Bottom">
        <beginButton>
            <Button id="submit" text="{i18n>submit}" press="onSubmit" class="sapUiTinyMargin"/>
        </beginButton>
        <content>
            <f:GridContainer>
                <f:layout>
                    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="5rem" columnSize="8rem" gap="1rem"/>
                </f:layout>
                <f:layoutS>
                    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="5rem" columnSize="10rem" gap="0.5rem"/>
                </f:layoutS>
                <f:layoutXS>
                    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="5rem" columnSize="10rem" gap="0.5rem"/>
                </f:layoutXS>
                <Label text="{i18n>req}" required="true">
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="3"/>
                    </f:layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Label id="txt" text="{i18n>cat}" required="true">
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="3"/>
                    </f:layoutData>
                </Label>
                <RadioButton id="rbtn1" text="{i18n>grq}">
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="4"/>
                    </f:layoutData>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton id="rbtn2" text="{i18n>frq}">
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="4"/>
                    </f:layoutData>
                </RadioButton>
                <TextArea id="txtarea" value="" placeholder="{i18n>typeq}" growing="true" growingMaxLines="10" width="100%">
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="7"/>
                    </f:layoutData>
                </TextArea>
                <Text text="{i18n>note}">
                    <f:layoutData>
                        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="7"/>
                    </f:layoutData>
                </Text>
            </f:GridContainer>
        </content>
    </ResponsivePopover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Expected result is the fragment will load with out errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The named aggregation **must** have the same namespace as the parent tag.

> The namespace of the parent control tag and the aggregation tag must be the same. [(Source)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/19eabf5b13214f27b929b9473df3195b)

In your case, the issue is in `<SomeSapMControl><f:layoutData>`. Remove the `f:` in `<f:layoutData>` so that it matches with the parent's (default) namespace.

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Core"
], Core => Core.attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], Fragment => Fragment.load({
  definition: `<f:GridContainer xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns="sap.m">
    <Label text="Label within GridContainer">
      <layoutData>
        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="3"/>
      </layoutData>
    </Label>
  </f:GridContainer>`
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content")))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.f,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

---

> "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.Label". Not sure what this means.

Within control definition, control developers can assign a default aggregation so that application developers can add children without having to put an aggregation name explicitly in the XML view definition. An example of this is `sap.f.GridContainer`. Its default aggregation is `items`.<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c5114bebe75ac38d0b38e3b24752200ba973d1fa/src/sap.f/src/sap/f/GridContainer.js#L212)</sup> Hence, you won't need to add `<f:items>` to add children there (See my code snippet above).

If, however, the control has no default aggregation and the child node name matches with none of the named aggregations, the XML processor will throw the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The `sap.m.Label` and the other controls cannot be used inside `sap.f.Gridcontainer` directly. You'll need to place them inside `<f:items>` first.

From the documentation: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.f.GridContainer%23overview

```
<f:GridContainer>
  <f:layout>
    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="5rem" columnSize="5rem" gap="1rem" />
  </f:layout>
  <f:layoutS>
    <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="4rem" columnSize="4rem" gap="0.5rem" />
  </f:layoutS>
  <f:items>
    <GenericTile header="Sales Fulfillment">
      <layoutData>
        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData rows="2" columns="2" />
      </layoutData>
    </GenericTile>
    <w:Card manifest="url-to-manifest">
      <w:layoutData>
        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData rows="6" columns="3" />
      </w:layoutData>
    </w:Card>
    <Panel>
      <layoutData>
        <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="4" />
      </layoutData>
      <Text text="Sales information" />
    </Panel>
  </f:items>
</f:GridContainer>
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not correct. Since GridContainer's default aggregation is `items`,  the error cannot have stemmed from missing the `<f:items>` node