# Error: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.f.cards.Header

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add the custom data aggregation to a card control header. I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work, I'm always getting the same error:

> **Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.f.cards.Header**

I also tried attaching the aggregation through the controller an it worked fine but I need it in my XML view.

This is my code:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="Dashboard2.Dashboard2.controller.View2" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:w="sap.ui.integration.widgets" xmlns:card="sap.f.cards" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
   xmlns:core="sap.ui.core.customData" xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds" xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data"
   xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls">
   <ScrollContainer height="100%" width="100%" vertical="true">
      <f:GridContainer snapToRow="false" id="containerid">
         <f:layout>
            <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="84px" columnSize="84px" gap="6px"/>
         </f:layout>
         <f:layoutXS>
            <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="70px" columnSize="70px" gap="6px"/>
         </f:layoutXS>
         <f:Card class="sapUiMediumMargin" width="300px" height="23rem" id="batchlectura">
            <f:layoutData>
               <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="4"/>
            </f:layoutData>
            <f:header>
               <card:Header title="{datos>Proceso}" subtitle="{path:'datos>Hora', formatter:'.formatter.Hour' }" iconSrc="sap-icon://insurance-house"
                  statusText="{path:'datos>Estatus', formatter:'.formatter.Estatus'}">
                  <customData>
                     <core:CustomData key="Name" value="Contactname"/>
                  </customData>
               </card:Header>
            </f:header>
            <f:content>
               <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" height='100%' width="100%" vizType='column'>
                  <viz:dataset>
                     <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{datos>/results}">
                        <viz.data:dimensions>
                           <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Week" value="1"/>
                        </viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:measures>
                           <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Estimado" value="{datos>Estimado}"/>
                           <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Actual" value="{datos>Actual}"/>
                        </viz.data:measures>
                     </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                  </viz:dataset>
                  <viz:feeds>
                     <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Estimado"/>
                     <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed2' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Actual"/>
                     <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Week"/>
                  </viz:feeds>
               </viz:VizFrame>
            </f:content>
         </f:Card>
      </f:GridContainer>
   </ScrollContainer>
</mvc:View>
```

Nothing seems to work.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654209/error-cannot-add-direct-child-without-default-aggregation-defined-for-control)

Comment: As the linked answer explains, the named aggregation should have the same namespace as the one from the parent. So it should be `<card:customData>` instead of the default ns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `<customData>` should be `<card:customData>` otherwise the default namespace which is `sap/m` will be used.