# Toolbar in Custom Control

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to put a toolbar in the custom table after the below code. When ever i add this there is an issue that resource is not available. Any suggestions are appreciated
I have implemented example from
https://github.com/bhardwaj-rahul/Copy-ctrl-c-From-Excel-To-Table-SAPUI5/commit/1ef4521dda976ef92b65774beaeca00e2129a5ba which copy paste from excel to table.

```
<c:CopyPasteTable id="tableId" items="{/Data}" class="sapUiSizeCompact">

<headerToolbar>
    <OverflowToolbar>
        <Button text=”{i18n>btnTxtPrintCountSheet}” type=”Emphasized” icon=”sap-icon://print” iconFirst=”true” enabled=”true” visible=”true”
                iconDensityAware=”false” class=”sapUiTinyMargin”/>
        <Button text=” ” type=”Emphasized” icon=”sap-icon://add” iconFirst=”true” width=”auto” enabled=”true” visible=”true” press=”onAddPress”
                iconDensityAware=”false” class=”sapUiTinyMargin”/>
    </OverflowToolbar>
</headerToolbar>
```

Comment: You should be getting an error that the framework "Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control …”. If that's the issue (which was confirmed by your comment), consider to mark this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59654209/5846045.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey if you use the namespace **c:** for your custom Table you also need to use this namespace **c:** for the aggregations of the control. In the [sample](https://github.com/bhardwaj-rahul/Copy-ctrl-c-From-Excel-To-Table-SAPUI5/blob/1ef4521dda976ef92b65774beaeca00e2129a5ba/WebContent/view/CopyPaste.view.xml) you copied the Aggregation items also is using the namespace **c:**.

```
<c:CopyPasteTable id="tableId" items="{/Data}" class="sapUiSizeCompact">

<c:headerToolbar>
    <OverflowToolbar>
        <Button text=”{i18n>btnTxtPrintCountSheet}” type=”Emphasized” icon=”sap-icon://print” iconFirst=”true” enabled=”true” visible=”true”
                iconDensityAware=”false” class=”sapUiTinyMargin”/>
        <Button text=” ” type=”Emphasized” icon=”sap-icon://add” iconFirst=”true” width=”auto” enabled=”true” visible=”true” press=”onAddPress”
                iconDensityAware=”false” class=”sapUiTinyMargin”/>
    </OverflowToolbar>
</c:headerToolbar>
```